# Event listener not being removed last iteration of a loop even though other code runs

Tags: javascript, foreach, addeventlistener, event-listener, removeeventlistener

```js
let selectMode = false;
const selectButton = document.getElementById("select");
let cards = [];

//ref function logic
function MouseOverWrapper(cardElem) {
    return function () {
        cardElem.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
    }
}
function MouseLeaveWrapper(cardElem) {
    return function () {
        cardElem.style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
}

let CardSelected = function() {};
let CardFlip = function() {};


function AddFlashCard(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const form = document.querySelector("form");
    const formData = new FormData(form);  
    const titleInput = formData.get("card-title-input");
    const frontInput = formData.get("card-front-input");
    const backInput = formData.get("card-back-input");
    const cardContainer = document.querySelector("#card-container");
    let currSide = "front";
   
   
    let card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList.add("card");

    let title = document.createElement("h3");
    title.classList.add("card-content-title");
    title.textContent = titleInput;

    let content = document.createElement("p");
    content.classList.add("card-content");
    content.textContent = frontInput;


    card.appendChild(title);
    card.appendChild(content);
    cardContainer.appendChild(card);
    
    //add flip functionality-------------------------------------

    CardFlip = function() {
        if(currSide == "front") {
            content.textContent = backInput;
            currSide = "back";
        } else {
    
            content.textContent = frontInput;
            currSide = "front";
        }
    };

    //re update length of cards array every time new card added
    cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card"); 

    card.addEventListener("click", CardFlip);

    //check if currently in select mode

    //this only runs if I click add 
    //THIS IS JUST UPDATING NEW CARDS TO FIT INTO SELECT MODE
    if(selectMode) {
        //add select mode capablity for card here SAME AS LINE 97 THIS HANDLES NEW CARDS ADDED WHILE IN SELECT, be aware may run multiple times for same card tho
        cards.forEach(cardElem => {
            cardElem.removeEventListener("click", CardFlip);
            cardElem.addEventListener("mouseover", MouseOverWrapper(cardElem));
            cardElem.addEventListener("mouseleave", MouseLeaveWrapper(cardElem));
        })
        
        
        //add select hover func while in select mode

    }




    return false;
}

//select button, get all cards at the time of "select"
selectButton.addEventListener("click", SelectMode);

function SelectMode() {
//toggle Select mode
if(selectMode == true) {selectMode = false;}
else {selectMode = true;}
console.log(selectMode);

//update value of cards to equal everything
cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

if(cards != null) {
    //add select hover func whiel in select mode for all cards alr there when select button clicked, smame logic as line 64, be aware may run multiple times for same card tho
    cards.forEach(cardElem => {
        console.log(cardElem);
        cardElem.removeEventListener("click", CardFlip);
        cardElem.addEventListener("mouseover", MouseOverWrapper(cardElem));
        cardElem.addEventListener("mouseleave", MouseLeaveWrapper(cardElem));
    })
}


}
```

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;

}

h2 {
    text-align: center;

}

h4 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.label {
   display: inline;
   padding-right: 1rem;
   
}

#submit {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 2rem;
}


#card-front-input {
    resize: none;
}

#card-back-input {
    resize: none;
}

#form-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
}

.formItem {
    margin: 0 1rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    

    
}

#box1 {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   margin-bottom: 1rem;
   margin-left: 3rem;
}

#box2 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#box3 {
    display: flex;
   justify-content: end;
}


.line {
    border-top: 0.1rem dashed grey;
}

textarea {
    max-width: 100%;
}

#card-container {
    margin: 0 5vw;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 1rem;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 20vh;
    
}

.card {
    border: 0.1rem solid black;
    width: 25vw;
    height: 20vh;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 0.86rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}



.card-hovered {
    background-color: lightblue;
    cursor:default
}

.card-selected {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: 0.25rem dashed darkblue;
    cursor:default
}

#cards-top-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.cards-top-item {
    margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
    <title>Flash Card</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Flashcard App</h1>
        <h2>Card Creation</h2>
    </header>
    <section>
        <form onsubmit="return AddFlashCard(event);" id="form-container">
            <div class="formItem" id="box1">
                <label for="card-title-input" class="label">Card Title:</label>
                <input type="text" name="card-title-input" id="card-title-input">
            </div>
            <div class="formItem" id="box2">
                <button type="submit" id="submit">Add Card</button>
            </div>
            <div class="formItem" id="box3">
                <label for="card-front-input" class="label">Card Front:</label>
                <textarea name="card-front-input" id="card-front-input" cols="30" rows="5" maxlength="160"></textarea>    
            </div>
            <div class="formItem" id="box4">
                <label for="card-back-input" class="label">Card Back:</label>
                <textarea name="card-back-input" id="card-back-input" cols="30" rows="5" maxlength="160"></textarea>    
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
    <br>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <br>
    <main>
        <div id="cards-top-container">
            <h1 class="cards-top-item" id="cards-H1">Cards</h1>
            <button class="cards-top-item" id="select">Select</button>
        </div>
        <h4>Click On Card To Flip</h4>
        <div id="card-container"></div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Making a flashcard app where you can select cards to do actions yet to be coded yet. When select mode is not on, you can click on cards to toggle between the front and back of them, I used an event listener for this referenced by CardFlip. I want to remove this event listener when I am in select mode so I can do something else when the user clicks on the car while in select mode. I looped through an array of all my cards to try and remove the event listener, but encountered some strange logic. The other lines of code in the loop run just fine (the events being added that handle the hover effect), but cardflip gets removed for only the last card in the array of cards. I have no clue why this would work perfect for the whole loop but suddenly for the last iteration run all lines of code but this removal of the eventlistener CardFlip. any cards I add after I toggled select mode work as intended, and do not allow the card to flip when I click on it.

First question being asked on stackoverflow, apologies if I did something unconventional. Thanks a lot! Again, I want CardFlip eventlistener to be removed from all cards when I go into select mode, but it is only doing it for the most recent card added before I clicked "Select" to toggle select mode and then every card added after that.

Comment: StackOverflow allows you to create snippets of HTML, CSS, and JS, which allows commenters to interact with and run your code. Could you mock up the minimal version of this that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: @Leland added it I believe :) thanks for the quick response

Comment: Not a minimal version. You don't need the header, the CSS, the card creation form... You just need a couple of cards in HTML, a default event handler, and a button to switch the event handler.

Comment: Try building your example without changing this HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/z9opfxnr/1/

Comment: @Leland I believe I set it up, only changed what was necessary. Same issue occurring (cardflip event not being removed in select mode), hopefully it saved all good for you to view

Comment: You're redefining `CardFlip` everytime you do "AddCard" - this means it's creating a whole new function each time. When you call `removeEventListener`, you need to reference the original function (which you are not keeping a reference of).

Comment: I'd suggest you change your listener functions to accept the `event` and use that object to retrieve the target element. This will make it much simpler. Are you opposed to using jQuery?

Comment: @Rylee Thanks, not opposed at all, haven't used it before but this could be a good opportunity to give it a chance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to keep most of your original code/style so that it's not too much of a change. There are definitely "neater" ways of doing this.

The main parts changed:

- Setup dynamic events (easy using jQuery but can be done in vanilla)
- Change functions to accept the event as the first argument
- Record/access element data using jQuery's `.data` method

```js
// define events
// by using $(document).on(event, target) we make this dynamic
// meaning we don't need to add an event listener to each ".card"
$(document)
  .on("click", "#select", SelectMode)
  .on("click", ".card", CardFlip)
  
  // NOTE:: These 2 functions can be replaced with CSS
  //        if they are purely cosmetic/visual.
  //        I've left them in for this example
  .on("mouseover", ".card", MouseOverWrapper)
  .on("mouseleave", ".card", MouseLeaveWrapper);
  
// global variables
let selectMode = false;
const selectButton = document.getElementById("select");
let cards = [];

// functions
function CardFlip(event) {
    if (selectMode) {
        // don't do anything if selectMode is true
        return;
    }
    
    const $card    = $(event.currentTarget);
    const cardData = $card.data(); // jQuery data store
    const $content = $card.find("p"); // get "p" elements inside this card
    
    // determine current side based on class
    // there are other ways to do this, but for simplicity
    // we can use a class
    if ($card.hasClass("back")) {
      $content.text(cardData.frontInput);
      $card.removeClass("back");
    } else {
      $content.text(cardData.backInput);
      $card.addClass("back");
    }
}

function MouseOverWrapper(event) {
    if (!selectMode) {
        // don't do anything if selectMode is false
        return;
    }
    
    // don't have to use jQuery if you're more comfortable
    // using vanilla JS
    const card = event.currentTarget;
    card.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
}

function MouseLeaveWrapper(event) {
    if (!selectMode) {
        // don't do anything if selectMode is false
        return;
    }
    
    const card = event.currentTarget;
    card.style.backgroundColor = "";
}

function CardSelected(event){
    const card = event.currentTarget;
    // ...your code...
};


function AddFlashCard(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const form = document.querySelector("form");
    const formData = new FormData(form);  
    const titleInput = formData.get("card-title-input");
    const frontInput = formData.get("card-front-input");
    const backInput = formData.get("card-back-input");
    const cardContainer = document.querySelector("#card-container");
    let currSide = "front";
   
   
    let card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList.add("card");

    let title = document.createElement("h3");
    title.classList.add("card-content-title");
    title.textContent = titleInput;

    let content = document.createElement("p");
    content.classList.add("card-content");
    content.textContent = frontInput;


    card.appendChild(title);
    card.appendChild(content);
    cardContainer.appendChild(card);
    
    // add data to card
    const $card = $(card);
    $card
      .data("backInput", backInput)
      .data("frontInput", frontInput);
    
    // no need to setup events here.
    // all are dynamic
    
    return false;
}

function SelectMode() {
  // simple toggle
  selectMode = !selectMode;
}
```

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;

}

h2 {
    text-align: center;

}

h4 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.label {
   display: inline;
   padding-right: 1rem;
   
}

#submit {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 2rem;
}


#card-front-input {
    resize: none;
}

#card-back-input {
    resize: none;
}

#form-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
}

.formItem {
    margin: 0 1rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    

    
}

#box1 {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   margin-bottom: 1rem;
   margin-left: 3rem;
}

#box2 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#box3 {
    display: flex;
   justify-content: end;
}


.line {
    border-top: 0.1rem dashed grey;
}

textarea {
    max-width: 100%;
}

#card-container {
    margin: 0 5vw;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 1rem;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 20vh;
    
}

.card {
    border: 0.1rem solid black;
    width: 25vw;
    height: 20vh;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 0.86rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}



.card-hovered {
    background-color: lightblue;
    cursor:default
}

.card-selected {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: 0.25rem dashed darkblue;
    cursor:default
}

#cards-top-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.cards-top-item {
    margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <h1>Flashcard App</h1>
        <h2>Card Creation</h2>
    </header>
    <section>
        <form onsubmit="return AddFlashCard(event);" id="form-container">
            <div class="formItem" id="box1">
                <label for="card-title-input" class="label">Card Title:</label>
                <input type="text" name="card-title-input" id="card-title-input">
            </div>
            <div class="formItem" id="box2">
                <button type="submit" id="submit">Add Card</button>
            </div>
            <div class="formItem" id="box3">
                <label for="card-front-input" class="label">Card Front:</label>
                <textarea name="card-front-input" id="card-front-input" cols="30" rows="5" maxlength="160"></textarea>    
            </div>
            <div class="formItem" id="box4">
                <label for="card-back-input" class="label">Card Back:</label>
                <textarea name="card-back-input" id="card-back-input" cols="30" rows="5" maxlength="160"></textarea>    
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
    <br>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <br>
    <main>
        <div id="cards-top-container">
            <h1 class="cards-top-item" id="cards-H1">Cards</h1>
            <button class="cards-top-item" id="select">Select</button>
        </div>
        <h4>Click On Card To Flip</h4>
        <div id="card-container"></div>
    </main>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You could definitely store the "state" of the card in the `data` as well (i.e. front or back). I thought I'd chuck in changing classes in case you wanted to tie that in with CSS